# Optimize CSS Delivery with a css library as Materialize css

Tags: google-pagespeed

I'm failing 1 unique point in [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.comunicate.com.co%2Fcheckout%2Findex.php&tab=mobile) in both Desktop and Mobile due to a CSS file, the "error" says:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>   Your page has 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in
>   rendering your page. None of the above-the-fold content on your page
>   could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load.
>   Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the
>   critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.

[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) recommendation says

> If the external CSS resources are small, you can insert those directly
>   into the HTML document, which is called inlining. Inlining small CSS
>   in this way allows the browser to proceed with rendering the page.
>   Keep in mind if the CSS file is large, completely inlining the CSS may
>   cause PageSpeed Insights to warn that the above-the-fold portion of
>   your page is too large via Prioritize Visible Content. In the case of
>   a large CSS file, you will need to identify and inline the CSS
>   necessary for rendering the above-the-fold content and defer loading
>   the remaining styles until after the above-the-fold content.

However, I'm using [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/) a CSS/JS library. Such library contains a big minimized css file that works for everything. I'm not able to extract the portions that are used in above-the-fold content and even keep it maintainable / updatable.

One option is load the css after window load event, but in this case, the app load ugly before the css is loaded.

Is there a way to accomplish the Google recommendations using libraries as Materialize CSS, Foundation or similar?.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code able to extract the CSS content used in a HTML document, this should be cached, libraries as materialize take 15 seconds to seek every selector in a 200-lines HTML in a t2.micro AWS instance.

```
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
ob_start();
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
.....

</body>
</html><?PHP
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$md5 = md5($html);
if($memcached->append($md5, NULL)==TRUE){
    echo $memcached->get($md5);
}else{
    //add to HTML in style labels the CSS Used and minimized the result
    $dom = new Dom;
    $dom->load($html);
    $style = '';
    foreach($css_files as $css_file){
        $md5CSS = md5_file($css_file);
        if($memcached->append($md5CSS, NULL)==TRUE){
            $cssParsed = $memcached ->get($md5CSS);
        }else{
            $cssContent = file_get_contents($css_file);
            $oSettings = Sabberworm\CSS\Settings::create()->withMultibyteSupport(false)/*->beStrict()*/;
            $oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($cssContent, $oSettings);
            $cssParsed = $oCssParser->parse();
            $memcached->set($md5CSS, $cssParsed);
        }
        foreach ($cssParsed->getContents() as $oItem) {
            if ($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\CSSList\KeyFrame)
                continue;
             if ($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\RuleSet\AtRuleSet)
                continue;
            if($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\RuleSet\DeclarationBlock){
                $oBlock = $oItem;
                $selectors = array();
                foreach($oBlock->getSelectors() as $oSelector)
                    $selectors[] = $oSelector->getSelector();
                if(count($dom->find(implode(",",$selectors))) > 0)
                    $style .= $oBlock->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
            }
            if ($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\CSSList\AtRuleBlockList) {
                foreach($oItem->getContents() as $oBlock) {
                    $selectors = array();
                    foreach($oBlock->getSelectors() as $oSelector)
                        $selectors[] = $oSelector->getSelector();
                    if(count($dom->find(implode(",",$selectors))) > 0){
                        $style .= $oItem->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    $styleLabel = '<style type="text/css">'.$style.'</style>';
    $html = str_replace("</head>", $styleLabel."\n</head>",$html);
```